# Script to remove certain span elements from an HTML file

Tags: shell-script, sed, perl, html

I want to write a script that completely removes every instance of a particular span class from a given HTML file.

For example, if my undesired span class is `"foo"` then running my script on the file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>hello world</title>
  </head>
  <body>
lorem ipsum
<span class="foo"> STUFF </span>
alpha beta <span class="foo"> MORE 
STUFF</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

should yield

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>hello world</title>
  </head>
  <body>
lorem ipsum
alpha beta 
  </body>
</html>
```

I have two questions.

1. Can this be done with `sed` or `perl`?
2. Is there a tool in linux that is designed to easily edit HTML documents like this?

Comment: What about `<span class="bar foo">`, possibly with a linebreak in it, and nested spans in your to-be-deleted range? General-case HTML manipulation is hard-to-impossible with regular-expression tools like `sed`, XSLT might be an approach with at least a different set of problems.

Answer (score 4):

Perl can do it, even across line breaks.

Dump this into a file (I'll call it example.html):

```
<p>Here is some <span>foo bar</span> example text.</p>
<p>Some text even <span>foo
bar</span> spans across line breaks.</p>
```

Then try it out:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/<span.*?<\/span>//gs' example.html
<p>Here is some  example text.</p>
<p>Some text even  spans across line breaks.</p>
```

Comment: Wouldn't be safer to modify this command as `perl -0777 -pe 's/<span.*?<\/span>//gs' example.html` to make sure that end of range is `</span>`?

Comment: Yes, you make a good point. I'll edit the answer to reflect your improvement.

Comment: Actually there are problems with the Perl code. What happens when `</span>` falls at the end of line, like as in the OP's case?  And more importantly, this will not handle the case of nested `<span>`.

Answer (score 3):

Provided your HTML is well formed XML you can do this with an XML processing tool such as `xmlstarlet`. Assuming the file is `original.html`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -O -d '/html//span[@class = "foo"]' original.html
```

Output

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>hello world</title>
  </head>
  <body>
lorem ipsum

alpha beta
  </body>
</html>
```